# Hive Error while executing a join query [Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException]

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

Can someone help with this error thrown while running the query in HIVE ?

```
SELECT p.esmp, a.KeyKey FROM prime_positions p FULL OUTER JOIN assets a ON p.esmp = regexp_replace(a.KeyKey, '"', '') limit 1;

2014-02-20 12:09:38,185 FATAL ExecMapper: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"accountid":",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\"CORP\",\"MEDIUM-TERM-NOTE\",,\"KTB 2 1/4 09/11/18\",\"ACTIV\",\"CORP\",\"FIN\",\"BANK\",\"CBNU\",\"TH\",\"TH\",\"TH\",\"KRUNG THAI BANK/\",,,false,\"ACTIV\",1000.0,false,false,false,false,false,,,false,false,true,0.0,0.0,0.0,\"K1\",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\"XS0823985113\",\"B838YS2\",\"Y49876AE8\",\"163505434\",,,,,,,\"DBT01224754\",\"EJ5780402 Corp\",\"KTB\",,,,\"5BQXCT10\",,,,\"BBG0046QF1B6\",,,,,,,,\"\",\"0\",,,,,,,,\"KRUNG THAI BANK PCL/CAYMAN ISLANDS\",\"7565710\",\"KY\",\"TH\",\"KY\",\"15242\",\"122329\",\"FIN\",\"BANK\",\"CBNU\",,\"BANK\",,,,\"TH\",,,\"34684915\",\"117708\",,,,,,500000000.0,,\"Asset\",\"163505434\",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\"USD\",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,false,\"SUN\",false,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0.0,2.25,\"FIX\",0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,\"2\",\"MTY\",\"STREET CONVENTION\",\"SUN\",500000000.0,,500000000.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0.0,,,,,,,","accounttype":null,"legalentity":null,"accountsrcsys":null,"issueccy":null,"baseccy":null,"tdquantity":null,"sdquantity":null,"price":null,"pricingfactor":null,"tdmarketvaluelocal":null,"sdmarketvaluelocal":null,"tdmarketvaluebase":null,"sdmarketvaluebase":null,"fxrate":null,"businessdate":null,"pricetype":null,"longshortind":null,"accounttypecode":null,"tdlongshortind":null,"sdlongshortind":null,"pricefactortype":null,"internalproductid":null,"preferredid":null,"preferredidtype":null,"ispledged":null,"isadjusted":null,"efamid":null,"sourcesystem":null,"esmp":null,"positionseq":null,"issuecountry":null,"assettype":null,"sedol":null,"cusip":null,"isin":null,"ticker":null,"quick":null,"opracode":null,"riccode":null,"region":null}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:259)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:253)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 195
```

Comment: Somehow get a feeling that it could be the regexp_replace. Can you try without that and see if it works. Also maybe try to escape the double quotes.